# How do I merge a date with a value in separate columns in R? ie D1 to S1, D2 to S2, D3 to S3 etc etc

Tags: merge

I have a df of patients (ID) all of whom had a polyps size (S1,S2,S3,S4,S5) removed at different time intervals (D1,D2,D3,D4,D5).

How can I merge this date to plot a line graph of size (S1,S2,S3,S4,S5) by Date (D1,D2,D3,D4,D5)

ID. d1  d2  d3  d4  d5  s1  s2  s3  s4 s5
A   10  14  15  20  23  5   7   10  2  4

S1 is the size recorded at D1 (date 1)

This is as far as I have got.....

```
important \<- c('ID','D1','D2','D3','D4','D5','S1','S2','S3','S4','S5')
df.smaller \<- df\[,important\]

df.plot \<- reshape2::melt(df.smaller\[,c('S1','S2','S3','S4','S5','ID')\], id='ID')

ggplot(df.plot, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=ID, colour=ID))+
geom_line(alpha=0.1)+
labs(x = "Time points (D1-D5)", y="Polyp size (mm)")+
ggtitle("Polyp size (mm) at different time points (n=1973)")+
guides(colour=FALSE)
```

Tried the above and just got a line plot of sizes S1, S2, S3, S4, S5 for each patient